# Rxjs: How to get last values when using bufferCount

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Is there any way to get the latests emitted values when using `bufferCount(x)` when the buffer size don't reach `x`.

Example: the code bellow print only `[0, 1]`. I expect the output to include `[2]` after some kind of condition.

```
const subject = new Subject();

subject.asObservable()
  .pipe(bufferCount(2))
  .subscribe(console.log);

for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) subject.next(i);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to complete the inner observable, like this:

```
subject.complete();
```

then `[2]` will be emitted as expected.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if it's possible to force a flush after some delay for example ? I tried something with `bufferTime` but it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: You could try using `takeUntil` with `timer`, like this: `subject.asObservable().pipe(takeUntil(timer(3000)), bufferCount(2))` - this will emit `[2]` after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **takeLast** operator to take the last n values emitted by the source Observable before it completes.
For example:

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { bufferCount, takeLast } from 'rxjs/operators';

const button = document.querySelector('button');
const click$ = fromEvent(button, 'click');

click$
  .pipe(
    bufferCount(5), // Buffer 5 clicks
    takeLast(1) // Take the last buffer
  )
  .subscribe(buffer => {
    console.log('Last buffer:', buffer);
  });
```

the **click$** Observable emits every time the user clicks the button. We use **bufferCount(5)** to buffer 5 click events and emit the buffer as an array. Then we use **takeLast(1)** to take the last buffer emitted by the source Observable before it completes. Finally, we subscribe to the resulting Observable and log the last buffer emitted.

It will log the last buffer of 5 click events emitted before the user stopped clicking the button. Please noted if the user only clicked the button once, it will log an array containing that single-click event.